# VideoView MediaController inside DialogFragment not showing (Xamarin Android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I have only been developing on Android for four months and I am relatively new to programming. I am trying to include some media controls for my videoView which inside a dialogFragment but am not able to see it when I tap on the videoView. I can only see it for half a second right after I click outside the videoView. Any ideas?

There is also an extra white space on the right of the videoView which won't disappear. Initially, I thought it was the title but I used `Dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);` and now it appears on the right.

Comment: I think you may want to have your video played in fragment or activity but in the meanwhile show the media control overlay on the video? Then you don't need to create such a layout in `DialogFragment`, the `MediaController` itself has this feature, or did I misunderstand your request?

Comment: I have the videoView on a dialogFragment but how should I have the MediaController overlay on the video?